# Which object has been on other planet(s) or other natural bodies the most times? What if orbits count?

Tags: interplanetary, record, planet, travel, trivia

Following answer(s) to [Which object has been to space the most times?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40244) answer, and related to [Objects that have been on the Moon multiple times](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39179) one.

**Question:** Are there any object(s) that travelled to more than one planet(s) or other natural bodies besides the Moon?

**update:** Per [OP's comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40254/which-object-has-been-on-other-planets-or-other-natural-bodies-the-most-times?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment130625_40254):

> I guess orbits can count.

the visits can include orbits around these bodies and don't necessarily require landing on each body.

Comment: Has anything actually been brought back from another planet at all? Other bodies, sure, but I don't recall anything taking a spin round a planet and coming back. Maybe you should expand your question to cover any other natural bodies, then there's at least a _small_ chance.

Comment: Thanks @StarfishPrime

Comment: I'm guessing the record is 1, for asteroid/comet sample return missions.

Comment: Do "been on" and "taken to" mean taken to the surface of planets (not possible for planets that lack any kind of solid or liquid surface)? Would orbit count?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I guess orbits _can_ count.

Comment: I've updated your question to reflect your comment and to adjust the language to better fit the site.